# After SampleData: store stopped working

Tags: magento2, sample-data

Local dev Magento 2.2.3 installation just stopped working.
I was developing Magento module.
Disabling module does not help.

When accessing http://localhost:8888/magento2/ Magento recomends

> Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory

Running `bin/magento setup:upgrade` doesn't help.

> The following modules are outdated:
>   Magento_ConfigurableSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0

All cache is OFF. `php -f bin/magento cache:flush` doesn't help.

**Complete exception stack trace**

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:
Magento_ConfigurableSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_OfflineShippingSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_CatalogRuleSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_CustomerSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_ThemeSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_ProductLinksSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_SalesRuleSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_SwatchesSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_ReviewSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_TaxSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_CmsSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_SalesSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_GroupedProductSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_WidgetSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_WishlistSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:
Magento_ConfigurableSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_OfflineShippingSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_CatalogRuleSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_CustomerSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_ThemeSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_ProductLinksSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_SalesRuleSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_SwatchesSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_ReviewSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_TaxSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_CmsSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_SalesSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_GroupedProductSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_WidgetSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_WishlistSampleData data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
#0 /Users/dkaigorodov/kuoll/distros/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->beforeDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#1 /Users/dkaigorodov/kuoll/distros/magento2/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#2 /Users/dkaigorodov/kuoll/distros/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#3 /Users/dkaigorodov/kuoll/distros/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 /Users/dkaigorodov/kuoll/distros/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#5 /Users/dkaigorodov/kuoll/distros/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#6 /Users/dkaigorodov/kuoll/distros/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#7 /Users/dkaigorodov/kuoll/distros/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#8 /Users/dkaigorodov/kuoll/distros/magento2/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#9 {main}
```

**UPDATE**

In database setup_module.data_version is NULL for the modules in the exception list above

**UPDATE 2**

After `composer update`

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (UnexpectedValueException): Setup version for module 'Magento_CatalogSampleData' is not specified

Exception #0 (UnexpectedValueException): Setup version for module 'Magento_CatalogSampleData' is not specified
#0 /Users/dkaigorodov/kuoll/distros/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Module/DbVersionInfo.php(54): Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->isModuleVersionEqual('Magento_Catalog...', '2.0.0')
#1 /Users/dkaigorodov/kuoll/distros/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Module/DbVersionInfo.php(77): Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->isSchemaUpToDate('Magento_Catalog...')
#2 /Users/dkaigorodov/kuoll/distros/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(120): Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->getDbVersionErrors()
#3 /Users/dkaigorodov/kuoll/distros/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(53): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->getGroupedDbVersionErrors()
#4 /Users/dkaigorodov/kuoll/distros/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->beforeDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#5 /Users/dkaigorodov/kuoll/distros/magento2/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#6 /Users/dkaigorodov/kuoll/distros/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#7 /Users/dkaigorodov/kuoll/distros/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#8 /Users/dkaigorodov/kuoll/distros/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#9 /Users/dkaigorodov/kuoll/distros/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 /Users/dkaigorodov/kuoll/distros/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#11 /Users/dkaigorodov/kuoll/distros/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#12 /Users/dkaigorodov/kuoll/distros/magento2/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#13 {main}
```

Comment: do you have a full page cache system in front of your web server. varnish or something. Try calling the hopepage url with an extra get parameter. `http://localhost:8888/magento2/?a=1` or something like that. Also check the table `setup_module` to see the versions of the modules that appear in the error message.

Comment: Hi, Marius.

http://localhost:8888/magento2/?a=1 gives same result.

`setup_module.data_version` is NULL for the modules in the exception list